# How to install Gmail apk on emulator (from Android Development Tools, ADT)?

Tags: gmail, linux, apk, android-emulator

I'm working on an email app for Android, and I'd like to install the Gmail apk on my emulator in order to test it.

How can I do that?

I have seen tutorials on how to do it on windows, but I'm working with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Sync your Google account in emulator, and go to Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

Go to sdk/platform-tools with the command `cd /home/android-sdk/platform-tools` you should copy the `.apk` you want to install in this directory and add the path of it to environment variable in variable PATH "you might need restart"`(PATH=$PATH:path to apk)`

List the devices with the command ./adb devices

You can install your file with ./adb install .filename.apk
Example for step 2 :

> ./adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
> emulator-5554    device

Example for step 3 :

> ./adb install AndExplorer.apk
>
> 1083 KB/s (338651 bytes in 0.305s)
> pkg: /data/local/tmp/AndExplorer.apk
> Success